# Calling api client to modify the data of parent api client call

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```
client.post(config.apiUrl+"cart", args, function(data,response) {

                if (data.status == 'success') {

                    for (var key in data.data.cart_items_list) {
                       if (data.data.cart_items_list.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                            data.data.cart_items_list[key].child.prodqty = function () {
                                client.get(config.apiUrl+"product/"+data.data.cart_items_list[key].child.child_id+"/quantity",  function(invdata, invresponse) {

                                    if(invdata.status == 'success'){
                                        console.log(invdata.data);
                                        return invdata.data;

                                        console.log(data.data.cart_items_list[key].child.prodqty);
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                       }
                    }

                    console.log(data.data.cart_items_list);
                }

        })
```

Above is piece of code I have written to get one modify the data I got from api client call.
The first api call will a json data. I am looping thru that data to get one value from another api and append to parent's json data

`console.log(data.data.cart_items_list[key].child.prodqty);` line prints the correct value in my logs, but `console.log(data.data.cart_items_list);` this is not having the newly(child.prodqty) appended value in it.

I am very much new in Node.js so I don't know whether I am doing it correct

EDIT:
if I `console.log(data.data.cart_items_list);` the output has prodqty in it. but its coming like this. `prodqty: [Function]`

Comment: I understand that the `console.log(data.data.cart_items_list);` doesn´t work. Its correct?? In this case use: `console.log(JSON.stringify(data.data.cart_items_list));`

Comment: @ErikLucio: Actually the new property is appending to the `data.data.cart_items_list` but its not having the desired value

Comment: you returning from async function, use callbacks or promises, also I not see the call of the `data.data.cart_items_list[key].child.prodqty`

Comment: initially `data.data.cart_items_list[key].child` does not have `prodqty`. I am trying to add it from the second api call. `console.log(data.data.cart_items_list[key].child.prodqty);' but this is printing the proper value in the logs.

Comment: Ah! Now I think understand your problem: You can access to `prodqty`. This value is asked in second api. And You expect that `prodqty` value is in `data.data.cart_items_list` after the loop for. Its correct??

Comment: @ErikLucio:yes correct. I am expecting the value from second api call to come in `data.data.cart_items_list`

Answer (score 0):

For default you say that `data.data.cart_items_list` get `prodqty: [Function]`. If you get the `prodqty` value you need to set this value in `data.data.cart_items_list`, thus you can catch it after the loop. I my opinion, I prefer to create a new var when I set it:

```
 client.post(config.apiUrl+"cart", args, function(data,response) {
                    var prodqty = {};
                    if (data.status == 'success') {

                        for (var key in data.data.cart_items_list) {
                           if (data.data.cart_items_list.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                                data.data.cart_items_list[key].child.prodqty = function () {
                                    client.get(config.apiUrl+"product/"+data.data.cart_items_list[key].child.child_id+"/quantity",  function(invdata, invresponse) {

                                        if(invdata.status == 'success'){
                                            console.log(invdata.data);
                                            return invdata.data;

                                 prodqty.key = data.data.cart_items_list[key].child.prodqty;  //prodqty associated with his key         
                         console.log(data.data.cart_items_list[key].child.prodqty);
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                           }
                        }
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(prodqty));
                        console.log(data.data.cart_items_list);
                    }

                })
```

I`ve added a object prodqty. Then I set the prodqty whit his key. I this structure of code there may be a problem. The api use a callback, then when loop finish is posible that the prodqty object doesn´t set the values. For resolve it, You need pass a callback at the second api or wait a time until second api finish:

```
setTimeout(function(){ console.log(JSON.stringify(prodqty)); }, 3000);` //3 seconds for example
```

Comment: I did modify my first API to include the value that I get from second API call.So i did not try your answer.Anyhow thanks for your valuable time. when I get time I will be checking this out